# unable to get os.getenv('HOSTNAME') work during the startup

Tags: python

I have python script which run during the start of the linux VM:

I have added it in the chkconfig 345

script is supposed to check the hostname and if it is localhost.localdom then it should exit

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess,platform,os,sys,logging,shlex

system_name = os.getenv('HOSTNAME')

if system_name == 'localhost.localdom':
    logging.info('Please correct host name for proxies, it is showing localhost')
    sys.exit()"
```

if I run it manually it works fine. But during the startup process, even though the hostname is localhost.localdom. It does not exit.

so it look like during the boot process,

```
os.getenv('HOSTNAME')
```

is not returning the localshot.localdom what I have set in condition.

Please help getting this to work during reboot.

Thanks,
Jitendra Singh

Comment: The HOSTNAME environment variable may not be set for the `rc` scripts. You could use the output of `/bin/hostname` or `/usr/bin/hostname` instead... that is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posting an answer using the info in Isedev's comment...

you could try getting the hostname by:

```
import os
system_name = os.popen('/bin/hostname')

if system_name.read().rstrip() == 'localhost.localdom':
    logging.info('Please correct host name for proxies, it is showing localhost')
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: using this it only returns a `<os._wrap_close object at 0x7699aa30>`. How does one get the actual `$HOSTNAME`